# jQuery Knob at low resolutions

Tags: jquery, jquery-knob

I'm trying to use [jQuery Knob](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob) in a mobile web app, so screen resolution of 320x480 (you can use http://www.resizemybrowser.com/ to test). However at this resolution the inner text is not displaying correctly, it's not displaying at all. I've tried messing with all of the options and the source to no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chrome Developer Tools (F12) of Firebug to check and modify live the properties, markup and styles on the knob so you can find what is really happening.

Comment: I've been doing this, but the jquery knob does a lot of manual pixel calculations in the source. Trying to see if anyone else has figured out the right things to tweak.

Comment: These calculation maybe are reflected on inline style in the markup. that could lead to a clue to see which overwrite by attaching to the events and modify after the ones from jquery knob